# Moving my Git bare repository to server is not correct

Tags: git, scp

I am trying to move my Git bare repository to a server like this.

```
$ scp -r my_project.git user@git.example.com:/opt/git
```

I do this from the folder where `my_project.git` exists. What I expect from previous experience is to have a `my_project.git` folder created inside `/opt/git` folder. But what I actually find in my server is very different. It has moved everything inside `my_project.git` to the server `/opt/git` folder but not the `my_project.git` folder. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What directory structure are you getting on the remote system, and what directory structure would you like to have?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I figured it out. I should have the folder already created on the server before doing this. If not it will create the folder but do what I tried to explain.